# Kendo autocomplete dynamic datasource (AngularJS, kendo ui)

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I don`t really understand why I cant call function in kendo autocomplete k-data-soruce.

index

```
<input kendo-auto-complete ng-model="filter.FilterValue" k-data-source="filteredData()" style="width: 100%;" />ter code here
```

controller

```
var test = ["aa", "ab", "ac", "zz"];
return test;
```

maybe someone can help

Comment: I have tried the same thing and found when you are passing function to k-data-source, it enters into a infinite digest cycle and even though autocomplete will come but it will not be able to select the value.

Better if you use $scope.variable and assign to k-data-source rather than using function, which is working perfectly

Comment: Thanks! Will look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have an example of how to do filtering from a method in AngularJS.

Please see this [dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/@sehaxx/iLetUFes).

```
  angular.module("KendoDemos", [ "kendo.directives" ])
      .controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){
          var data = ["Albania", "Andorra", "Armenia", "Austria"];              
          $scope.countryNames = function(){
            return data;
          }                
      })
```

Hope this will help you.

Cheers,